# Can I change the directory for scratch files in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

The default directory is `%HOMEPATH%\.<product><version>\config\scratches`.
It's not so easy to use.
So can I change it to other directories as `C:\scratches`?
If so, I can open a REPL and easily add 'c:\scratches' to the sys.path. Then I can load modules in scratches.

Comment: Why not just create a shortcut to `%HOMEPATH%\config\scratches` and put it on your desktop?

Comment: If I want to import a module from scratch folder in REPL, it's still inconvenient.

Comment: Perhaps it'd help to update your question with your use case(s).

Comment: You are right, I should make the question more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Just necroing this in case anyone stumbles upon it from searching.  But, I guess you can now change the location to save scratch files from the default.

In PyCharm, click the "**help**" menu and then click "**Edit Custom Properties**"

This will open an idea.properties file with the first line shown below as a comment:

```
custom PyCharm properties (expand/override 'bin\idea.properties')
```

Now just add the following code to this file and of course, change to whatever folder you want.  And yes, the slashes should be forward slashes as shown:

```
idea.scratch.path/scratches=C:/Users/Johnny/Documents/MyCodeFiles/PyCharm/MyScratchesFolder
```

Now just close out of the properties file (no saving needed) and then restart PyCharm.  Your scratches folder should now be showing the new location on the left.  And you can also copy/paste your previous scratch files from the default location to your new folder.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue for this on the JetBrains tracker - you could join the discussion there:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-183154